# How can one set java.base/java.util=all-unnamed in Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, netbeans

I have a backend springboot application i'm working on, using Spring Web, Lombok and MongoDb dependencies, but i've been getting an error with major problem stated below;

`**unable to make protected java.util.calendar() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module**`

I made some searches and discovered i can set java.base/java.util=all-unnamed jvm option. But some said this method is not the best.
Does anyone know how i can best solve this problem?

I have tried setting the jvm option to no avail, though i'm not sure if i did it right. I visited the project properties, then saw VM options, then i pasted the java.base/java.util=all-unnamed stuff therein.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Community Bot, i've been able to solve the problem by replacing java.util.Calendar in my project entities to LocalDateTime.

Answer (score -1):

I've been able to solve the problem by replacing `java.util.Calendar` in my project entities to `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35829890)

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev given there is no other answer, this can't be a thank you.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel This post looked different when it was in the low quality queue, it was a copy of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78203703/how-can-one-set-java-base-java-util-all-unnamed-in-netbeans-ide/78210360?noredirect=1#comment137882447_78203703) comment. But I agree it looks strange, I was sure there was another answer here.